# flask jinja2 href not linking correctly

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have a jinja2 template that contains hrefs

```
<td><a href="{{entry.Url}}">Product URL</a></td>
```

However, when I run the application and click the link on the page I get the development server in front of the correct url.  So it would look like the following in the browser:

```
http://121.1.2.1:8764/www.google.com/
```

When I just want the following link:

```
www.google.com
```

Any ideas on how I can get this to work?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know this for fact, but do you need to add `http://` to links in Jinga?

Comment: Just tested, and in fact, you do have to add `http://` to the URL so the template creates an external link.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This worked for me while testing.

```
<a href="{{ ''.join(['http://', entry.Url]) }}">{{ entry.Url }}</a>

# entry.Url == www.google.com
# <a href="http://www.google.com">www.google.com</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Without adding a prefix, the root of the URL will be your local environment. In this case it's your IP address.

To correct the issue, add a `HTTPS` prefix like so:

```
<a href="https://{{ entry.Url }}">{{ entry.Url }}</a>
```